# How to read ANSI encoded files in the right way?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, arabic, ansi

I have some files that Ubuntu can't read it ( ANSI encoding ) but Windows can read it well.

When I open it in *gedit* or *notepad*++ it seems like this :

> Êã ÇáÊÍæíá áÜÜ

How can I make Ubuntu read ANSI encoded files well?

Comment: There is really no such thing as “ANSI encoding”. Only a bad joke of some 1980s coders working in Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANSI [means more or less nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format) --- the most probable candidate for your encoding is Windows-1252. You can convert the file with

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t utf8 < filein.txt > fileout.txt
```

but remember, most [encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (read the linked article if you are not sure about what that mean)  [can't be reliably guessed](http://unicodebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guess_encoding.html), so you need to know the exact encoding to give sense to your data.

From the comments it seems that you are most probably looking for some Arabic encoding --- in that case check `WINDOWS-1256`.

The list of available encodings for `iconv` is [on github](https://gist.github.com/hakre/4188459), or you can find it with the command

```
iconv --list
```

Notice that just at the start of the list there are a bunch of "ANSI"-like encodings.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to convert it as mentioned in Rmano's answer, you may use Geany or Kate to read/edit them ar they are, default Arabic encoding in Windows is CP-1256 (`WINDOWS-1256`). Just keep in mind that switching to UTF-8 is recommended over all. It is supported by Notepad++ and Windows default note editor.

### Geany

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

[image: geany encoding]

### Kate

```
sudo apt-get install kate
```

[image: kate encoding]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to read a file in **ANSI mode** in **ubuntu** and was able to do it.

I tried sublime text, gedit, etc. but I was somehow failing, finally I tried the **terminal** in ubuntu, and cat command helped me.

I opened the terminal in the file location then used

`cat filename.txt`

And it worked like a charm,
 if the text file contains the ANSI syntax, it will be displayed properly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The gedit can work with files encoded with e.g. Windows-1250. Select "Open", "Additional Documents", Character encoding: "Central European (WINDOWS-1250"). If it is not there, add it there by this option.